# why the listFragment with black background?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listfragment

I  build the listFragment but running it display black background.

look like that , left is the layout.xml look in eclipse layout editor, right is ruuning in emulator:

[image]

and I build the other new project to compare, this look is what I want white background black text:

[image]

I compare two projects.. every thing is match.. 
`values/styles.xml` `values-v11/styles.xml` and `values-v14/styles.xml` are same in two project..

and here selection  are same also:
[image]

so whats the matter????

Comment: can u post ur layout xml code?

Comment: I think the xml is not the point,because I use the project one xml put in project two..it also show the white background black text normal..

Comment: try set listview background attribute is white color.

Comment: can you try my solution?

Comment: yes.. thats work if set the attribute, but I dont know why it will show two looking with same layout... oh= = your name is funny,just I think you are visitor..   @StackOverflowUser

Comment: can you accept my below answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this follow solution it will work

on your xml layout add attribute `android:background` assign to what you what color or from drawable resources.

```
<ListView 
   android:id="@+id/hlveqproducts"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@android:color/white"
  />
```